Random Network Error in Axiom+vue+laravel
So, I have a Laravel + Vue 3 app, that uses Axiom to send requests to get data from external API service. Sometimes i get complains from clients, that they get an error, and most of the time it's "Network Error", i don't have that error, don't know how to reproduce it, and even if i get to look in devtools in their browser, all i see is blank request, that doesn't have any information other than "network error". I tried hard reload (Ctrl + F5), and it doesn't work. This error occurs on this request only, other work fine. Please help me
Code:
 let data = JSON.stringify({
                SESSION_ID: this.sessionId,
                CLIENT_PHONE: phone,
                CERTIFICATE_CODE: "" + this.certificateCheckData.number,
                CERTIFICATE_CHECK_CODE: "" + this.certificateCheckData.code,
            });

            let config = {
                method: "post",
                maxBodyLength: Infinity,
                url:
                    import.meta.env.VITE_1S_API_URL +
                    import.meta.env.VITE_1S_GET_CERTIFICATE_DATA,
                data: data,
                auth: {
                    username: import.meta.env.VITE_USR,
                    password: import.meta.env.VITE_PWD,
                },
            };

Cleaning cache, hard reload, opening in private mode didn't work
It's not CORS, as other requests pass normally
